# Android ndk 22 configuration

Tags: android, android-ndk, qt-creator

I'm trying to add the 22.0.7026061 NDK to Qt creator, but this version does not contain the platforms folder. Qt creator uses the following code to check the validity of the NDK and as a result I cannot add the 22nd version. In addition, I did not find any clear explanation why this paltrforms does not exist.

```
    bool AndroidConfig::isValidNdk(const QString &ndkLocation) const
{
    auto ndkPath = Utils::FilePath::fromUserInput(ndkLocation);
    const Utils::FilePath ndkPlatformsDir = ndkPath.pathAppended("platforms");

    return ndkPath.exists() && ndkPath.pathAppended("toolchains").exists()
           && ndkPlatformsDir.exists() && !ndkPlatformsDir.toString().contains(' ')
           && !ndkVersion(ndkPath).isNull();
}
```

What can I do? I need exactly the 22nd version, the versions below are normally added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Changelog-r21](https://github.com/android/ndk/wiki/Changelog-r21):

> The legacy toolchain install paths will be removed over the coming
> releases. These paths have been obsolete since NDK r19 and take up a
> considerable amount of space in the NDK. The paths being removed are:
>
> - platforms
> - sources/cxx-stl
> - sysroot
> - toolchains (with the exception of toolchains/llvm)

As for what you can do? I don't think much, you'll have to patch this part of Qt to use newer directories (e.g `toolchains/llvm` for `platforms`). You can also report this as a bug to Qt devs.